# feeding Ajax data in React

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, reactjs, react-router, jsx

I'm still relatively new to React. Slowly, I'm trying to integrate react as a front end for my MVC website, however I seem to be stuck on migrating an AJAX call into my EmployeeGrid Table. 
For my Index I'm doing the following

```
<Route exact path='/' component={Intro} />
<Route exact path='/Home/GSC' component={GSC} />
```

The Intro works fine, and GSC partially works. The data is not showing in the table. This is what I have in my GSC.js

```js
import React from 'react';

function EmployeeGridRow() {
    <tr>
        <td>{this.props.item.AccountID}</td>
        <td>{this.props.item.AccountName}</td>
        <td>{this.props.item.SenderName}</td>
        <td>{this.props.item.SenderEmail}</td>
        <td>{this.props.item.ITEmailReceipients}</td>
        <td>{this.props.item.Active}</td>
    </tr>;
}

class EmployeeGridTable extends React.Component {
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            items: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        //Fetch data via ajax
        $.get(this.props.dataUrl, function (data) {
            if (this.isMounted()) {
                this.setState({
                    items: data
                });
            }
        }.bind(this));
    }
    
    render() {
        var rows = [];
        this.state.items.forEach(function (item) {
            rows.push(
                <EmployeeGridRow key={item.AccountID} item={item} />);
        });
        return (
            <table className="table table-bordered table-responsive">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Sender</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>IT Support</th>
                        <th>Active</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {rows}
                </tbody>
            </table>);
    }
}

export default EmployeeGridTable(dataUrl = "/Home/GetEmployeeData");
```

Any suggestions?

---

Update

I'm thinking that maybe I didn't explain well. The following below works, but only if I insert it into a .cshtml. Is there any way of converting this into a JS or JSX file?

```
<script type="text/babel">
@* Here we will create 2 react component 1 for rows and another for table  *@
var EmployeeGridRow = React.createClass({
render : function(){
return (
<tr>
    <td>{this.props.item.AccountID}</td>
    <td>{this.props.item.AccountName}</td>
    <td>{this.props.item.SenderName}</td>
    <td>{this.props.item.SenderEmail}</td>
    <td>{this.props.item.ITEmailReceipients}</td>
    <td>{this.props.item.Active}</td>
</tr>
);
}
});

var EmployeeGridTable = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function(){
return {
items:[]
}
},
componentDidMount:function(){
@* Fetch data via ajax *@
$.get(this.props.dataUrl, function(data){
if(this.isMounted()){
this.setState({
items: data
});
}
}.bind(this));
},
render : function(){
var rows = [];
this.state.items.forEach(function(item){
rows.push(
<EmployeeGridRow key={item.AccountID} item={item} />);
});
return (
<table className="table table-bordered table-responsive">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Sender</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>IT Support</th>
            <th>Active</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {rows}
    </tbody>
</table>);
}
});
ReactDOM.render(
<EmployeeGridTable dataUrl="/Home/GetEmployeeData" />,
document.getElementById('griddata')
);
```

Comment: Have you confirmed you're getting data back? E.g. `console.log(data)` in the ajax callback?

Comment: No, it doesn't return data. However when I convert it into babel on the cshtml page, I am able to get data back and the table populates. (I do not wish to use Babel).

Comment: `this.isMounted()` is useless here, the `componentDidMount` method is called when your component is already mounted, as indicated by the method name

Comment: When you say "convert it into Babel" - are you just using the above in a js file and referencing that??

Comment: A few small changes, but yea pretty much. I use the above in a cshtml file with a script tag 'text/babel'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not provide the props like this, you are in fact instantiating the component when you should only provide the class or function to be instantiated in other components.

```js
export default EmployeeGridTable;
```

In other components:

```js
<Route exact path='/' component={Intro} />
<Route exact path='/Home/GSC' component={() => <GSC dataUrl="/Home/GetEmployeeData" />} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Functional component EmployeeGridRow receives props as param and so to access item it should be props.item but not this.props.item

Change

```
    function EmployeeGridRow() {
<tr>
    <td>{this.props.item.AccountID}</td>
    <td>{this.props.item.AccountName}</td>
    <td>{this.props.item.SenderName}</td>
    <td>{this.props.item.SenderEmail}</td>
    <td>{this.props.item.ITEmailReceipients}</td>
    <td>{this.props.item.Active}</td>
</tr>;
 }
```

To

```
    function EmployeeGridRow(props){
        <tr>
           <td>{props.item.AccountID}</td>
           <td>{props.item.AccountName}</td>
           <td>{props.item.SenderName}</td>
           <td>{props.item.SenderEmail}</td>
           <td>{props.item.ITEmailReceipients}</td>
           <td>{props.item.Active}</td>
      </tr>;
    }
```